How do I panic the build of a Vue 2 project if an environment variable is not set?
In a Vue 2 project, an environment variable (let it be VUE_APP_IMPORTANT_VAR, for example) is mandatory, so I want to get a failed build if somebody has forgotten to specify the variable in .env (or in another way). I tried this code:
/* main.js */
...

if (!process.env.VUE_APP_IMPORTANT_VAR) {
  console.error("Critical: VUE_APP_IMPORTANT_VAR is not set")
  throw 1
}

...

But this obviously gives successful build. So how do I break the build if the variable is not set?

You could have 15 different ways to make the build crash yes, but it's probably not a thing to do in the codebase itself, more in a Vite/bash script.

@kissu Could you, please, provide some of these 15 ways that could be best practices in my and similar issues?

Env var is set on build and you're supposed to fail a build rather than doing this at runtime in main.js. This is specific to your setup, which was omitted. VUE_APP_ prefix suggests this is Vue CLI, but there should be no place for guesswork

Could use a linter, use a bash script to check the existence of such a variable in the scope, run some tests, have some Jenkins or alike checking that your variable is populated, use dotenv [etc...]
